# How to Navigate to the Next Page in a Pagination Element Using Selenium WebDriver in Python?

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, google-colaboratory

I’m trying to navigate through a pagination element on a webpage using Selenium WebDriver in Python. The HTML structure of the pagination element is as follows:

```html
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="paginate_button previous" id="datatable_previous">
        <a href="#" aria-controls="datatable" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0">Précédent</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button ">
        <a href="#" aria-controls="datatable" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button active">
        <a href="#" aria-controls="datatable" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">2</a>
    </li>
    <!-- More page numbers... -->
    <li class="paginate_button next" id="datatable_next">
        <a href="#" aria-controls="datatable" data-dt-idx="8" tabindex="0">Suivant</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to click the `Suivant` button to go to the next page. However, the `<a>` tag inside the `Suivant` button has `href="#"`, so it doesn’t change the URL when clicked. I tried using Selenium’s `click()` method to click the button, but the page content doesn’t change.

Here’s the code I’m using:

```
def scrape_bloc_files(soup):
    for i, pdf in enumerate(soup.select("tr a[target='_blank']")):
        pdf_link = pdf['href']
        driver.get(pdf_link)
        time.sleep(1)


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
    "download.default_directory": "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Files/resumes",
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True
})
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/chromium-browser'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.offre-emploi.tn/consulter-cv/')
time.sleep(1)

try:
    html = driver.page_source
except UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
    alert = driver.switch_to.alert
    alert.accept()
    html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

while True:
    try:
        next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li#datatable_next a"))
        )
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_button)
        scrape_bloc_files(soup)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Couldn't click the next button: {e}")
        break

driver.quit()
```

Does anyone know why the page content isn’t changing and how I can successfully navigate to the next page? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check devtool to find what js code were executed when click suivant, then execute that js code by selenium?

Comment: `href="#"` This usually means the link has a javascript function attached to it.

Comment: @JohnGordon so is there any solution to call the nex page ?

Comment: try something like: next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@id='datatable_next']/a"))
        ) next_button.click()